# NTP local query always times out

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, ntp

I have a CentOS 6.4 server, it does not have any iptable rules, it runs NTP daemon as service using the following configuration:

```
  driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

  server 0.pool.ntp.org
  server 1.pool.ntp.org
  server 2.pool.ntp.org
  server 3.pool.ntp.org

  restrict default ignore
  restrict 127.0.0.1
```

When I run `ntpq` to query peers, the following response is received:

```
ntpq> peers
localhost.localdomain: timed out, nothing received
```

`dig` shows that:

```
localhost.localdomain.  86400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

Why doesn't ntp query work?

Comment: Do you have a local IPtables running?

Comment: iptable is running, but there isnt any rule.

Comment: And ntp-daemon is actually running? Try `grep ntp /var/log*` to see if there are some notices which might help?

Comment: are you able to ping `0.pool.ntp.org` and others in the list ?

Comment: Do you have an entry for localhost or localhost.localdomain in /etc/hosts?
The system will look here first, before checking DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was expecting `ntpq` to query local server via 127.0.0.1, but it turns out to be querying local server via ethernet network interface.

Although I have no idea why a local ntp query would have to go through ethernet, but in configuration file I added

```
restrict <eht0 ip address>
```

And now NTP works fine.

Comment: Is this actually safe? Ie would that give public access somehow?

Answer (score 11):

On RHEL / CentOS 6 and 7, for whatever reason `ntpq` tries to query the IPv6 loopback at ::1 instead of the IPv4 loopback at 127.0.0.1. With this in mind, I added this line to my `/etc/ntp.conf` file:

```
restrict ::1
```

Saved the file then restarted `ntpd`

```
service ntpd restart
```

now the command:

```
ntpq -p
```

works as expected. (This is the same as running `ntpq` in command-line mode and then issuing the `peers` command.)

I prefer this solution since you do not have to enable communications with `ntpd` via a potentially public Ethernet interface, which may be a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

When read the second answer, I realize the reason of this issue which maybe on /etc/hosts.
Then add localhost on /etc/hosts and retry, it works.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Before:

```
ems@rack6-storage-2:~$ sudo service ntp stop ; sudo ntpdate 0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org ; sudo service ntp start ; PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin ntpdc -p
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd
   ...done.
18 Dec 08:18:31 ntpdate[35729]: adjust time server 202.156.0.34 offset -0.000467 sec
 * Starting NTP server ntpd
   ...done.
localhost.sdcorp.global.sandisk.com: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

After:

```
ems@rack6-storage-2:~$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
ems@rack6-storage-2:~$ sudo service ntp stop ; sudo ntpdate 0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org ; sudo service ntp start ; PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin ntpdc -p
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd
   ...done.
18 Dec 08:27:09 ntpdate[36056]: adjust time server 202.156.0.34 offset 0.015872 sec
 * Starting NTP server ntpd
   ...done.
     remote           local      st poll reach  delay   offset    disp
=======================================================================
=golem.canonical 10.242.43.103   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 4.00000
=frontier.innola 10.242.43.103   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 4.00000
=sg01.7asecond.c 10.242.43.103   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 4.00000
=time2.maxonline 10.242.43.103   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 4.00000
=pontoon.latt.ne 10.242.43.103   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 4.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable IPv6 if you do not use it, add the following in interface configuration file:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0           
....
IPV6INIT="no"
....
```

Then apply via restarting network and ntpd services.
This helped to me.

Answer (score -2):

People should read more carefully given configs before they are suggesting "reinstall". The mistake is very obvious.

From what I see, you have configured an NTP **SERVER** but you are pointing that to a **POOL**

> server 0.pool.ntp.org

Try

> pool 0.pool.ntp.org

instead or use "server" with a dedicated server, not a pool.

Comment: That just shouldn't matter, as the `pool` directive just resolves more IP addresses behind the *0.pool.ntp.org* alias, where as the `server` directive just resolves one address from DNS and sticks to it.